# (Unity3d) Why is video texture on quad has less quality than original video?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures

When I use a material to assign video texture to a quad or rawImage, result quality is not as good as original video. Why?
I used exact size (1920 1080) as orig. video to prevent convert size problems. But the result is very bad.

[image: original video]

[image: quad]

to clarify I use Keijiro procAmp chroma key plugin

**EDIT**: May be it is not clear enough in images. But in second image there is no soft edges and horizontal lines make output video very low quality if you notice

**EDIT2**: After start a bounty, I know to find how can I fix the issue?

Comment: Is it as bad as you said when you start your 'game'?

Comment: I can't give you an answer, but sometimes,depending on pc parametres, when you start your game, or you're on preview, you might have different results

Comment: Both in editor and after build. quality is not good

Comment: What are your texture import settings? Not enough info in your question to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's difficult to perceive the drop in quality based on your screenshots.

Answer (score 6):

This is likely the result of real-time rendering, in combination with how you render the video in the RawTexture, and its lack of rendering filters/options.
 Possibly also rendering it with an incompatible material, maybe one that is affected by lighting?

Your post definitely doesn't have enough info for anyone to be able to tell..

---

In any way, your solution would be to either render to a RenderTexture, with some poking around its anti-alliasing and mipmap settings (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html)

or play the video from a VideoPlayer directly (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer.html).

I would begin with the Video Player option, and see how that goes, since that's Unity's built-in solution for videos.

The Render Texture provides you more rendering options, but the outcome of the quality heavily depends on how you render the video to it.